# 6-Pin Battery Connector to 2 Wire Terminal Connection

Tags: connector, pins, pcie

I have a 16V 6-Pin battery. I am trying to get it so that I am going from a 6-pin connection to a 2 wire connection. I have been unable to find any adapter online so I went ahead and cut off the connector and soldered wires to the power and ground. When I hook up the connections to my multimeter it reads 0V. What I suspect to be the case is that there is an enable pin that is deactivated that is preventing voltage from flowing. Am I on the right track? 
[image: The makeshift soldered connections on the left and the initial 6 pin connection on the right]
Any input or advice in tackling this problem would be welcome. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Welcome to EE SE! What type is that battery? And what is the function of each pin?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. The battery is a rechargeable lithium-ion battery. Max charge is 16.8 V and max current is 2A. The battery is new and should have a charge to it. I have been unable to find anything on it regarding a pin layout specific to the battery. I assumed it was universal and was going off of this diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spsgx.png

Comment: Pinout for common connectors for generic PC has nothing to do with your battery. What it is for? Appliance? Robot? Camera?

Comment: It powers a manikin, so a robot in a way, yeah.

Comment: Most likely every series cell joint has a pin for external balancer or BMS and possibly 1 pin for a thermistor for temp sensing. You can figure these out with a DMM.